# Slow wifi connection ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, connection

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and everything was fine before moving to my new room and now I have a very slow internet connection here. The connection speed is ok on windows and my ios phone. my laptop model is Lenovo IP320 and the wireless card is Realtek Semiconductor rtl8821ce.

the result for *nmcli dev wifi list* is as follows:

IN-USE  SSID                     MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
*       Vodafone            Infra  11    405 Mbit/s  86      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA

Answer (score 2):

First, I recommend that you establish a baseline for signal strength. Please run the terminal command:

```
nmcli dev wifi list
```

Please take note of the Signal reading for your router. Now let's try a driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r 8821ce
sudo modprobe 8821ce rtw_ant_num=1
nmcli dev wifi list
```

Is there any improvement in the signal? If not, try:

```
sudo modprobe -r 8821ce
sudo modprobe 8821ce rtw_ant_num=2
nmcli dev wifi list
```

I suspect that one of these settings will result in a noticeable improvement. Make the driver parameter permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options 8821ce rtw_ant_num=X"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/8821ce.conf
exit
```

...where X is the setting that you find offers the greatest improvement.

Comment: hi, the signal strength is full and I have tried everything but no luck :(

Comment: The signal strength is full, meaning high (??) and your connection is still slow. Is that what you are saying? Please clarify.

Comment: yes, the signal strength is high but still my connection to the internet is very slow. I tried many suggested ways but nothing happened

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `nmcli dev wifi list` Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar things, many ways and orders have been done but still slow. then I found a simple tip by removing the check mark on "`make available to another users`"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejlrr.png

Comment: I tried but unfortunately nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

With a rtl8821ae (lspci | grep Wireless)

Clone the repository

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git

cd rtlwifi_new
```

Compile and install the drivers in own Linux

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Unload the adapter module:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8821ae
```

For a more permanent change to your adapters options you must create a driver configuration file. Create the following Realtek rtlwifi driver configuration file.

```
/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8821ae.conf
```

Copy and paste the following into the conf file:

```
options rtl8821ae swenc=1

options rtl8821ae ips=1

options rtl8821ae rtw_power_mgnt=0

options rtl8821ae rtw_enusbss=0

options rtl8821ae swlps=1

options rtl8821ae fwlps=1

options rtl8821ae debug=1

options rtl8821ae disable_watchdog=1

options rtl8821ae msi=1
```

Reload the adapter module.

sudo modprobe rtl8821ae

If this configuration doesn't work, you can test changing the values